# Undocumented syntax highlighting languages

Tags: discussion

I've just discovered that AMPscript (a scripting language for Salesforce Marketing Cloud) supports syntax highlighting in SFSE using the language tag `lang-ampscript` after the code fence (```` ``` ````). Where did that come from?! I've always used javascript syntax highlighting before. Here's one of [my AMPscript answers with code highlighting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/323367/5449).

Oh, wait, there's one for Apex too! (`lang-apex`).

```apex
Integer x, sign;
// Your code
if (x <= 0) {
    if (x == 0) {
           sign = 0; 
    } else  {
           sign = -1;
    }
}
```

Is there a complete list of undocumented syntax highlighting for other languages (SOQL, Visualforce, etc)?

Comment: Just a note that while this might work now (when the stackexchange network is still using prettify), there is a plan to migrate to highlight.js. So this might not work forever.